# How to user the object "FiscalyYearSettings" in the custom formula field?

Tags: formula

I want to use the standard object "FiscalYearSettings" in the custom formula field. But it seems that the system can not distinglish this object. 
Can anyone tell me whether we can use this object in the creation of a custom formula field? If we can, how can we do that?
I want to dispaly the start date of the fiscal year: $FiscalYearSettings.STARTDATE

Thanks

Best regards,
Jiahuan

Comment: You can't use FiscalYearSettings.Startdate as a merge field in date formula fields.  You can create a custom field on your object with a trigger to retrieve that information and update the field.  It seems your post is related to this idea.
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000aEJEAA2